# Compiling with ANT using external libs

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I'm new with `ANT` and I'm trying to compile part of my Eclipse project. I have many classes but i need to pack only a part of it (please don't ask why). My problem is that one of these classes references to an external library placed in the `<project_root>/libs` folder and I did not find out how to link it. I found examples on the web but I was not able to arrange it.

```
<path id="classpath">
    <fileset dir="libs" includes="**/*.jar"/>
</path>

<target name="compile">
    <mkdir dir="client/classes"/>
    <javac srcdir="src" destdir="client/classes" sourcepath="classpath">
        //include needed java files
    </javac>
</target>
```

I'm using the annotation `@Remote` of `EJB`. It's in the `javax.ejb` package. I get the error:

```
package javax.ejb does not exist
[javac] import javax.Ejb.Remote;
```

Comment: can you send the error you actually get? Is your problem the compiling with the missing lib or is your issue to collect all the files for the final jar or war file? You are referencing /lib in your description, but your ant file points to "lib_s_".

Comment: Sorry, of course the directory name is libs. I get the error code that the package for the referenced class does not exist and it cannot find the Symbol. I added some info above.

Comment: This link gives build.xml examples, including classpaths: http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one

```
<classpath>
   <fileset dir="libs">
      <include name="**/*.jar"/>
   </fileset>
</classpath>
```

Comment: Yes i've just seen... Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your project structure correctly, the issue with your ant file is that you reference the classpath as beeing the sourcepath.

sourcepath / sourcepathref point to locations where source can be found. I suppose what you want is **classpathref**="*classpath*".

```
<javac srcdir="src" destdir="client/classes" classpathref="classpath">
    //include needed java files
</javac>
```

Comment: ...what do you want to say with this statement?

Comment: You did not explicitely reference to the classpath in your javac statement. You added a sourcepath statement that seems misplaced here. My suggestion was to replace the sourcepath with the classpathref.